# Code coverage Cypress and Storybook, can't instrument my code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, code-coverage, cypress, storybook

I'm trying to work with Cypress and Storybook for visual testing in a React Typescript project. 
The main goal is to render all my components library with Storybook and then visit them through Cypress and have the code coverage in order to pass it to SonarQube.

The problem is the instrumentation with Storybook, I have found no mentions about it. For example I run my server with the following script : `react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start`

The "`-r @cypress/instrument-cra`" will generate the coverage files while Cypress runs and it works great.

Then with Storybook : `start-storybook`, it run but no code coverage is generated because the app isn't instrumented.

I wish i could do something like : `start-storybook -r @cypress/instrument-cra` but the "-r" argument is part of react-scripts and I don't know how to reproduce with Storybook.

Is there an another way to get it working, or do I have missed something after hours or searching ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add [babel-plugin-istanbul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul) to the [babel config that storybook is using](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-babel-config/).

Essentially recreating what instrument-cra is doing:
https://github.com/cypress-io/instrument-cra/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Unfortunately babel-plugin-istanbul won’t work - it hangs the storybook launch.